# How to make a startup command uTorrent server

Tags: command-line, server, startup, make, utorrent

My issue that after reboot, I must enter this command using SSH PuTTY.

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ -daemon
```

After this command I can access the uTorrent IP page.

How can I make it start up automatically?